# C++ dynamically allocated array of statically dimensioned arrays

Tags: c++, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation, dynamic-arrays

I need to create a structure that holds a variable number of 'char[2]'s, i.e. static arrays of 2 chars.

My question is, how do I allocate memory for x number of char[2].

I tried this (assuming int x is defined):

```
char** m = NULL;
m = new char[x][2];
...
delete [] m;
```

(it didn't work)

I realise I could use std::vector<char[2]> as a container, but I'm curious as to how it would be done with raw pointers.

I am very new to C++ and trying to learn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code, the type of 'm' doesn't match your 'new' call.  What you want is:

```
char (*m)[2] = NULL;
m = new char[x][2];
...
delete [] m;
```

m is a pointer to arrays of 2 chars, and you call new to get an array of x arrays of 2 chars and point m at the first one.

Comment: @j_random_hacker, It's a "pointer to array of 2 chars". No array of them. "array of pointer to array of 2 chars" looks like `char (*m[N])[2];`, and could be used if you did N independent such `new` calls :) +1 @Chris xD

Comment: You're absolutely right -- how did I mess that up?! I've deleted that misleading comment.

Comment: +1. Though it's often easier to use a typedef: `typedef char char2[2]; char2 *m = new char[x][2];`

Answer (score 4):

I believe that the following code is more readable than `char[n][2]`:

```
typedef char wchar[2];   // array of two chars
const size_t n = 100;    // some const
wchar* x = new wchar[n]; // array of wchars, where wchar is array of two chars

// here is still a problem that you could write the following
x[5][5] = 0;             // not what you expected?

delete[] x;              // clean up
```

If we aware of the internal structure of wchar, the code will be more readable if we declare it as follows:

```
// using struct is just gives names to chars in wchar, without performance drop
struct wchar {
  char h;
  char l;
};

...

const size_t n = 100;    // some const
wchar* x = new wchar[n]; // array of wchars

x[0].h = 0;
x[0].l = 0;

delete[] x;              // clean up
```

And finally, because we use C++, no need to use C arrays:

```
const size_t n = 100;    // some const   
typedef std::tr1::array<wchar, n> my_arr;
my_arr* x = new my_arr;

(*x)[0].h = 0;
(*x)[0].l = 0;

delete x;
```

One more pretty safe option with compile time range checking:

```
template<int n_max>
struct array_n {
    char v[2*n_max];

    template<size_t n, size_t s> 
    char& get() {
        BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT( s < 2 );
        BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT( n < n_max );
        return v[n*2+s];
    };  
};

int main( int argc, char**argv)
{
    const size_t n = 100;    // some const   
    typedef array_n<100> my_arr;
    my_arr* x = new my_arr;

    x->get<10, 1>() = 0;   // ok
    x->get<50, 0>() = 0;   // ok
    x->get<10, 2>() = 0;   // compile time error
    x->get<500, 0>() = 0;  // compile time error

    delete x;
}
```

Comment: Nice. One thing to be aware of with the `typedef` approach is that if you happen to allocate a single `wchar` (*not* an array of `wchar` -- e.g. `wchar* m = new wchar;`), you must *still* delete it with `delete [] m;`. litb noticed this ugly hole in another thread.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Those are all easier ways to do it.

Comment: @j_random_hacker, that's why to use `struct` is more preferable.

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned x=10;
typedef char A2[2];
A2 *m=new A2[x];
m[0][1]='a';
m[9][0]='b';
delete[] m;
```

C multi-dimensional arrays (where all but the first dimensions are constant) are laid out contiguously.

If you want a (potentially jagged) multi-dimensional array which is a 1d array of 1d arrays, then you have to loop:

```
  char **m=new char *[x];
  for (unsigned i=0;i<x;++i) m[i]=new char[2];
  ...
  for (unsigned i=0;i<x;++i) delete[] m[i];
  delete[] m;
```

Answer (score 0):

You would end up determining the size of the array, and then use new, and treat it as a two-dimensional array.

But, for a good discussion on this you may want to look at:
http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t283481-dynamic-multidimensional-arrays.html