# A dynamic 2 dimensional array in C++?

Tags: c++

I am trying to build a 2 dimensional array in C++ while I don't know how many rows I will have. Here is some code:

In the header file:

```
class model
{
         ... ...

    float vertices[][3];

         ... ...
}
```

And in the .cpp file:

```
 istringstream iss(str);
 for (int i = 0; i <=2; i++)
     {
         iss >> vertices[counter][i];
     }
```

Is this a proper way to handle it? I got a segmentation fault, I just want to make sure it's not caused by the way I use arrays. Also is there a better way to handle this, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to either use pointers, or use a dynamically resizable container such as `std::vector` when you don't know the size.

Comment: And I'd recommend wrapping a *single* vector. Use math to calculate it's 1D index from a 2D index. Usually simpler and faster.

Comment: @GMan: I would not say so as one of the dimension is fixed (3).

Comment: @GMan: But if the application requires operations like "insert into row 1 when there are things in row 2," then shifting everything around can become prohibitively expensive.  Actually, if the nested vectors are staggered at all it will become expensive...

Comment: `std::vector< std::tr1::array<float, 3> >`

Comment: Missed that one was fixed. @mloskot's solution seems nice.

Answer (score 1):

A `Type variable[];` appears in a struct/class definition actually means a [zero-length array](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html#Zero-Length) which is a gcc extension (ISO C++ doesn't allow this) for a flexible array with a variable length known in *compile-time*.

(You should use `std::vector` or `new Type[n]` as others have suggested.)

Answer (score 1):

In case one of dimensions is of static size, here is one of many possible solutions:

```
typedef float triplet[3];
std::size_t const n = 10;
triplet* a = new triplet[n];

for (std::size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    // ...
}
delete [] a;
```

I'd suggest to use [Boost.MultiArray](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/multi_array).

A very similar question has been already asked and answered with plenty of examples

[C++ dynamically allocated array of statically dimensioned arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408866/c-dynamically-allocated-array-of-statically-dimensioned-arrays)